# Remove last line from multi-lined variable

Tags: perl, text, expect, text-manipulation

How can I remove the few lines from a multi-lined variable?

I'm getting this sort of stuff back from Expect and need to neaten it up a little bit

```
$var='

total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 drew.jess users 4096 2013-01-22 15:51 bash
drwxr-xr-x 2 drew.jess users 4096 2011-11-11 10:37 diff
drwxr-xr-x 8 drew.jess users 4096 2012-02-14 09:09 expect
drwxr-xr-x 3 drew.jess users 4096 2011-10-06 11:05 perl 
drwxr-xr-x 3 drew.jess users 4096 2013-02-07 13:10 python
drew ~ $

';
```

Those blank lines are representative of what I have. Ideally, I want to make $var look like this:

```
$var='
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 drew.jess users 4096 2013-01-22 15:51 bash
drwxr-xr-x 2 drew.jess users 4096 2011-11-11 10:37 diff
drwxr-xr-x 8 drew.jess users 4096 2012-02-14 09:09 expect
drwxr-xr-x 3 drew.jess users 4096 2011-10-06 11:05 perl 
drwxr-xr-x 3 drew.jess users 4096 2013-02-07 13:10 python
';
```

I should clarify; the important part of this question to me is the removal of the following line:

```
drew ~ $
```

The whitespace, I think I can cope with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression like `s/^[^\S\n]*\n//gm` will remove all lines that contain only whitespace.

**Update**

If you want to do something more than just remove blank lines, then it is best to `split` the string into lines and remove the ones you don't want. This code uses `grep` to remove lines that are all-whitespace and then `pop` to remove the last one.

```
my @lines = grep /\S/, split /\n/, $var;
pop @lines;
$var = join '', map "$_\n", @lines;
print $var;
```

**output**

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 drew.jess users 4096 2013-01-22 15:51 bash
drwxr-xr-x 2 drew.jess users 4096 2011-11-11 10:37 diff
drwxr-xr-x 8 drew.jess users 4096 2012-02-14 09:09 expect
drwxr-xr-x 3 drew.jess users 4096 2011-10-06 11:05 perl 
drwxr-xr-x 3 drew.jess users 4096 2013-02-07 13:10 python
```

Comment: Glad to help. The problem is that the data isn't organised as "lines" and "remove all the blank lines, plus the last non-blank one" isn't a trivial procedure!

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a regex substitution:

```
$var =~ s/^\s*$//gm;
```

`\s*` will match newline, but also other whitespace which you probably do not want. `^` and `$` and beginning and end of line anchors. The `/m` modifier allows the anchors to match inside the string, at start/end of lines (e.g. at newlines).

Comment: This won't delete the last blank line before a non-blank one, because `/$/m` matches only *before* a newline (or at the end of the string).

Comment: @Borodin Huh, that's odd. I also discovered that `\z` and `\Z` do not work with the `/m` modifier.

Comment: I think it's a documentation bug. `$` matches *before* a terminating newline and at the end of the string. `$` with `/m` also matches before *any* newline. `\z` and `\Z` seem fine to me - `\Z` has the same behaviour as `$` behaviour without `/m`, i.e. the end of the string or before a newline at the end. `\z` just matches the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

From [this perlmonks answer](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=574298)

$var =~ s/(^|\n)[\n\s]*/$1/g;

Lots of ways to do this though. No problems just looping through and deleting blank lines in my opinion.

Comment: this was a particularly good solution for the whitespace, thank you!  any ideas about the last line removal?  :)

Comment: If you just want to remove the final trailing newline you can call chomp on the entire variable e.g.
chomp($var)

Comment: how about the text on that last line too?  effectively i want the line that looks like

drew ~ $\n

to be removed

Comment: @drew: See the update to my answer to do more than just remove blank lines

Answer (score 0):

You can simply trim whitespace like you would do with a single-line string and add a terminating newline:

```
$var =~ s/^\s+//;  # Trim whitespace from beginning of string
$var =~ s/\s+$//;  # Trim whitespace from end of string
$var .= "\n";      # Add terminating newline
```

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of a different solution that does not use regular expressions, you could use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) in a loop:

```
for ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    1 while chomp $var;
    $var = reverse $var;
}
```

Comment: This will not effect the additional blank lines at the beginning of the string.